# Problems with query and validation in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, validation

Here the SQL sentence

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nombre' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `producto` where `nombre` = Chaqueta Andes B-Dry Hoody Jacket)
```

Here Validation/Request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'nombre' => 'required|string|max:50|unique:producto',
        'precio_venta' =>'required|numeric|min: 1',
        'tipo_de_producto' => 'required',
        'marca' => 'required',
        'detalle_producto' => 'required|string|max:200',
        'foto_producto' =>  'required|image',
    ];
}
```

How can i add an alias from 'nombre' to 'nom_producto'

ej: 'nombre', alias: 'nom_producto' in sql statement, it's possible?

pd: sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Here the SQL sentence ERROR, sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a second parameter to the `unique` validator that is the name of the column in the database: `unique:<table_name>,<column_name>`

`'nombre' => 'required|string|max:50|unique:producto,nom_producto'`

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique

Comment: thanks, i did not see it in documentation, i am blind